# Why does password validation returns false?

Tags: kotlin, validation

In kotlin, when I enter valid passwords, the password validation function still returns false, even for not null or empty passwords. What's missing?

SignupScreen.kt

```
package com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens

   
@Composable
fun SignUpScreen(signupViewModel: SignupViewModel = viewModel()) {

    val passwordError by signupViewModel.passwordError.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState()}
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    val passwordVisible = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }


    Scaffold( snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState)
        },

    ){it
        //Screen content
     Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(28.dp)
                ) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(state=scrollState),verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {

                        NormalTextComponent(value = stringResource(id = R.string.hello))
                        HeadingTextComponent(value = stringResource(id = R.string.create_account))
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

                        MyTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.first_name),
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile),
                            onTextChanged = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.FirstNameChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.firstNameError
                        )

                        MyTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.last_name),
                            painterResource = painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile),
                            onTextChanged = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.LastNameChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.lastNameError
                        )

                        MyTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.email),
                            painterResource = painterResource(id = R.drawable.message),
                            onTextChanged = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.EmailChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.emailError
                        )

                        OutlinedTextField(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            value = signupViewModel.password,
                            onValueChange = signupViewModel::changePassword,
                            leadingIcon = {
                                Icon(painter = painterResource(id=R.drawable.ic_lock), contentDescription = "")
                            },
                            trailingIcon = {

                                val iconImage = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                                    Icons.Filled.Visibility
                                } else {
                                    Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff
                                }

                                val description = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                                    stringResource(id = R.string.hide_password)
                                } else {
                                    stringResource(id = R.string.show_password)
                                }

                                IconButton(onClick = { passwordVisible.value = !passwordVisible.value }) {
                                    Icon(imageVector = iconImage, contentDescription = description)
                                }

                            },
                            singleLine = true,
                            visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible.value) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
                            isError = !passwordError.successful
                        )
                        //Confirm Password TextField

                        OutlinedTextField(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            value = signupViewModel.confirmPassword,
                            onValueChange = { signupViewModel.confirmPassword = it },
                            leadingIcon = {
                                Icon(painter = painterResource(id=R.drawable.ic_lock), contentDescription = "")
                            },
                            trailingIcon = {

                                val iconImage = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                                    Icons.Filled.Visibility
                                } else {
                                    Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff
                                }

                                val description = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                                    stringResource(id = R.string.hide_password)
                                } else {
                                    stringResource(id = R.string.show_password)
                                }

                                IconButton(onClick = { passwordVisible.value = !passwordVisible.value }) {
                                    Icon(imageVector = iconImage, contentDescription = description)
                                }

                            },
                            singleLine = true,
                            visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible.value) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
                            isError = !passwordError.successful
                        )
                        if (signupViewModel.isNotMatching) {
                            Text(text = "Passwords do not match!",
                            color = Color.Red)
                        }

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
                            .height(8.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth())

                        Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)) {
                            ConditionRow(condition = "Minimum 8 characters", check = passwordError.hasMinimum)
                            ConditionRow(condition = "Has special character", check = passwordError.hasSpecialCharacter)
                            ConditionRow(condition = "Has capitalized letter", check = passwordError.hasCapitalizedLetter)
                        }

                        CheckboxComponent(onTextSelected = {
                            BetteHomesAppRouter.navigateTo(Screens.TermsAndConditionsScreen)
                        }
                        ) {
                            signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.PrivacyPolicyCheckBoxClicked(it))
                        }

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))

                        ButtonComponent(
                            value = stringResource(id = R.string.register),
                            onButtonClicked = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.RegisterButtonClicked)
                                BetteHomesAppRouter.navigateTo(Screens.GeoMarkerScreen)
                                if (signupViewModel.userExists.value){
                                scope.launch { snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("The email address is already in use by another account!") }
                            }},
                            isEnabled = signupViewModel.allValidationsPassed.value
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

                        DividerTextComponent()

                        LoginClickableTextComponent(tryingToLogin = true,onTextSelected = {
                            BetteHomesAppRouter.navigateTo(Screens.LoginScreen)
                        })
                    }

                }

                if(signupViewModel.signUpInProgress.value) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                }

            }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ConditionRow(
    condition: String,
    check: Boolean
) {
    val color by animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = if (check) Color.Green else Color.Red,
        label = "text color"
    )

    val icon = if (check) {
        Icons.Rounded.Check
    } else {
        Icons.Rounded.Close
    }

    Row {
        Icon(
            imageVector = icon,
            tint = color,
            contentDescription = "status icon"
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
        Text(
            text = condition,
            color = color
        )
    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun DefaultPreviewOfSignUpScreen() {
    SignUpScreen()

 

    package com.example.loginflow.data.rules

object Validator {

    fun execute(password: String): PasswordValidationState {
        val validateSpecialCharacter = validateSpecialCharacter(password)
        val validateCapitalizedLetter = validateCapitalizedLetter(password)
        val validateMinimum = validateMinimum(password)

        val hasError = listOf(
            validateMinimum,
            validateCapitalizedLetter,
            validateSpecialCharacter
        ).all { it }

        return PasswordValidationState(
            hasMinimum = validateMinimum,
            hasSpecialCharacter = validateSpecialCharacter,
            hasCapitalizedLetter = validateCapitalizedLetter,
            successful = hasError
        )
    }

    fun validateFirstName(fName: String): ValidationResult {
        return ValidationResult(
            (!fName.isNullOrEmpty() && fName.length >= 2)
        )

    }

    fun validateLastName(lName: String): ValidationResult {
        return ValidationResult(
            (!lName.isNullOrEmpty() && lName.length >= 2)
        )
    }

    fun validateEmail(email: String): ValidationResult {
        val emailRegex = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+".toRegex()
        return ValidationResult(
            (!email.isNullOrEmpty() && email.matches(emailRegex))
        )
    }

    fun validatePassword(password: String): ValidationResult {
        return ValidationResult(
            (!password.isNullOrEmpty() && password.length >= 4)
        )
    }

    fun validatePasswordmatch(password:String, confirmPassword: String): ValidationResult{
        return ValidationResult(
            (password == confirmPassword)
        )
    }

    fun validatePrivacyPolicyAcceptance(statusValue:Boolean):ValidationResult{
        return ValidationResult(
            statusValue
        )
    }

    private fun validateSpecialCharacter(password: String): Boolean =
        password.contains(Regex("[!@#\$%^&*()_+\\-=\\[\\]{};':\"\\\\|,.<>/?]"))

    private fun validateCapitalizedLetter(password: String): Boolean =
        password.matches(Regex(".*[A-Z].*"))

    private fun validateMinimum(password: String): Boolean =
        password.matches(Regex(".{8,}"))
}

data class ValidationResult(
    val status: Boolean = false
)
```

SignupViewModel:

```
class SignupViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val TAG = SignupViewModel::class.simpleName

    var registrationUIState = mutableStateOf(RegistrationUIState())

    var allValidationsPassed = mutableStateOf(false)

    var signUpInProgress = mutableStateOf(false)

    var userExists = mutableStateOf(false)

    var password by mutableStateOf("")
        private set
    // match password and confirm password
    var confirmPassword by mutableStateOf("")

    val isNotMatching by derivedStateOf {
            password != confirmPassword
        }




    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    val passwordError =
        snapshotFlow { password }
            .mapLatest { Validator.execute(it) }
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
                initialValue = PasswordValidationState()
            )

    fun changePassword(value: String) {
        password = value
    }

    fun onEvent(event: SignupUIEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is SignupUIEvent.FirstNameChanged -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    firstName = event.firstName
                )
                printState()
            }

            is SignupUIEvent.LastNameChanged -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    lastName = event.lastName
                )
                printState()
            }

            is SignupUIEvent.EmailChanged -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    email = event.email
                )
                printState()

            }


            is SignupUIEvent.PasswordChanged -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    password = event.password
                )
                printState()

            }

            is SignupUIEvent.ConfirmPasswordChanged -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    confirmPassword = event.confirmPassword
                )
            }

            is SignupUIEvent.RegisterButtonClicked -> {
                signUp()
            }

            is SignupUIEvent.PrivacyPolicyCheckBoxClicked -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    privacyPolicyAccepted = event.status
                )
            }
        }
        validateDataWithRules()
    }


    private fun signUp() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside_signUp")
        printState()
        createUserInFirebase(
            email = registrationUIState.value.email,
            password = registrationUIState.value.password
        )
    }

    private fun validateDataWithRules() {
        val fNameResult = Validator.validateFirstName(
            fName = registrationUIState.value.firstName
        )

        val lNameResult = Validator.validateLastName(
            lName = registrationUIState.value.lastName
        )

        val emailResult = Validator.validateEmail(
            email = registrationUIState.value.email
        )


        val passwordResult = Validator.validatePassword(
            password = registrationUIState.value.password
        )
        val confirmPasswordResult = Validator.validatePasswordmatch(
            password = registrationUIState.value.password,
            confirmPassword = registrationUIState.value.confirmPassword
        )

        val privacyPolicyResult = Validator.validatePrivacyPolicyAcceptance(
            statusValue = registrationUIState.value.privacyPolicyAccepted
        )


        Log.d(TAG, "Inside_validateDataWithRules")
        Log.d(TAG, "fNameResult= $fNameResult")
        Log.d(TAG, "lNameResult= $lNameResult")
        Log.d(TAG, "emailResult= $emailResult")
        Log.d(TAG, "passwordResult= $passwordResult")
        Log.d(TAG,"confirmPasswordResult=$confirmPasswordResult")
        Log.d(TAG, "privacyPolicyResult= $privacyPolicyResult")

        registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
            firstNameError = fNameResult.status,
            lastNameError = lNameResult.status,
            emailError = emailResult.status,
            passwordError = passwordResult.status,
            confirmPasswordError = confirmPasswordResult.status,
            privacyPolicyError = privacyPolicyResult.status
        )


        allValidationsPassed.value = fNameResult.status && lNameResult.status &&
                emailResult.status && passwordResult.status && privacyPolicyResult.status

    }


    private fun printState() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside_printState")
        Log.d(TAG, registrationUIState.value.toString())
    }


    private fun createUserInFirebase(email: String, password: String) {

        signUpInProgress.value = true


        FirebaseAuth
            .getInstance()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside_OnCompleteListener")
                Log.d(TAG, " isSuccessful = ${it.isSuccessful}")


                signUpInProgress.value = false
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    BetteHomesAppRouter.navigateTo(Screens.GeoMarkerScreen)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside_OnFailureListener")
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception= ${it.message}")
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception= ${it.localizedMessage}")
                userExists.value = true
                //Observe this signUpUIState in SignUpScreen and show SnackBar using Scaffold in SignUpScreen

            }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce the results. The given code works for me. Also, what's the point of `isNullOrEmpty` on something that cannot be `null`?

Comment: I used this github example:https://github.com/droid-lover/AppsUsingJetpackCompose/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nativemobilebits/loginflow/data/rules/Validator.kt

Comment: Maybe the password just contains one pr two characters? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: @dan1st I entered valid password with capital letter, small letters and special characters.

Comment: Can you please give us an example password and the _minimal_ code that doesn't accept that example password?

Comment: One thing you may want to look at is the logic of `val hasError = listOf(...).all{it}` that has reversed meaning. `hasError` is false when an error is present and the other way around.

Comment: @DavidSoroko That part of the code works just fine, It shows 8 characters, capitalized letters, small letters, and special characters checked (right). In essence it validates the password and cofirmpassword fields. But I don't know why passwordResult returns false in validateDataWithRules method.